# How do I use an entire cacheGroup as an entrypoint in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

My webpack.config has entrypoints defined like this

```
config.entry = {
    'assessment-tile-view': { import: './assessment-tile-view/index.js', dependOn: 'vendors' },
    'assessment-tile-config': { import: './assessment-tile-config/index.js', dependOn: 'vendors' },
    vendors: <help_me_here>
  };
```

I have created a cacheGroup in `config.optimization` overriding the default `vendors` group. How do I use that cacheGroup as the shared entrypoint so that I don't need to specify an array of unending modules like `react`, `react-dom`, `loadash`, `moment`, `redux` etc.

### Edit

What I am trying to avoid:

```
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
assessment-tile-view (1.21 MiB)
      ./3015/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./94/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./1321/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./5653/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2062/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./459/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2499/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./8279/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./4569/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./1888/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.material-ui/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.lodash/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.babel/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.core-js-5e25e51c/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.core-js-3062047c/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.gql-query-builder/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.reselect/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.regenerator-runtime/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.react-i18next/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.popper.js/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.immer/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.reduxjs/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2325/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      assessment-tile-view-15d0b00a/main.css?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-15d0b00a/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      assessment-tile-view-98ee5d67/main.css?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-98ee5d67/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-fc66841c/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-aa8b97a4/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-c28ed554/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-view-8f7142db/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
  assessment-tile-config (1.34 MiB)
      ./3015/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./94/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./1321/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./5653/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2062/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./459/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2499/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./8279/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./4569/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./1888/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.material-ui/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.lodash/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.babel/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.react-color/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.tpl-solution-library-ui-common-9755654c/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.tpl-solution-library-ui-common-188c4f13/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.tpl-solution-library-ui-common-ab6b6240/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.dom-serializer/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.htmlparser2/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.reactcss/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.domutils/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.recompose/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.entities/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.material-ui-color-picker/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.domhandler/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.icons/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.xtend/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.tinycolor2/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.style-it/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.string_decoder/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.sanitize-html-react/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.safe-buffer/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.regexp-quote/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.react-select/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.react-input-autosize/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.material-colors/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.inherits/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.events/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.domelementtype/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./npm.classnames/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./2325/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      assessment-tile-config/main.css?v=79890949a390c9af8184
      ./assessment-tile-config/bundle.js?v=79890949a390c9af8184
```

**Main chunk of webpack config file:**

```
  config.entry = {
    'assessment-tile-view': { import: './assessment-tile-view/index.js', dependOn: 'vendors' },
    'assessment-tile-config': { import: './assessment-tile-config/index.js', dependOn: 'vendors' },
    vendors: 'vendors'
  };
  config.optimization = {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      maxAsyncRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      maxSize: 256000,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
            // or node_modules/packageName
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
          priority: -10
        }
      }
    }
  };
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      // babel-loader will allow use of ES6 syntax in .js or .jsx files
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(third-partylib|fourth-party-lib)\/).*/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  targets: 'defaults',
                  useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                  corejs: 3
                }
              ],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ],
            plugins: [
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
              ['transform-react-remove-prop-types', { removeImport: true }]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'common/assets/img/[hash][ext][query]'
        }
      },
      // loader for processing font files
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'common/assets/fonts/[hash][ext][query]'
        }
      },
      // loader for processing sass templates used by react files
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          mode === 'production'
            ? {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: { publicPath: '../' }
              }
            : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

**Maybe I am wrong all the way, but I just wanna decrease my entrypoint size. Is lazy loading/dynamic import the only option now?**

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve doing that? Webpack is able to create a bundle of shared dependencies automatically with the `SplitChunksPlugin` or `optimization.splitChunks` since v4+. Is there a reason you don't use that instead?

Comment: @trixn good question. Although the plugin or optimization does create a split of `node-modules` for me, it still becomes a part of both of my top two entry points thus increasing the size of the entrypoints. I don't completely understand why it's a fuss made by webpack because I have already got them as vendor chunks but you know just trying to keep webpack happy...

Comment: Can you share your `optimization.splitChunks` config? Normally you wouldn't need to add an extra entry for the `vendors`. Webpack will create that automatically and write it to the output and there is also no need to explicitly declare your other entry points as dependent on that. Webpack should figure that all out automatically.

Comment: @trixn can you check why my entrypoint behaves this way then? I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you share your entire webpack config please?

Comment: @trixn please help :)